# Как вывести содержимое JS в отдельный блок div по клику?

Tags: html

В верхней части сайта есть поиск, в нижней - таблица. Допустим, при вводе определенного слова выдаёт 3 результата, каждый результат содержит в себе данные из таблицы в базе данных (MySQL). Задача заключается в том, чтобы при клике на определённый результат выводить все данные о нём в таблицу, что находится в нижней части сайта.
При нажатии на результат выдаёт просто пустое значение, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что в какой-то момент затирается значение `$row['provider']`, вероятно у тебя там нормальный такой винегрет из кода. Попробуй так:

```
echo "<div onclick=\"cock('" . $row['provider'] . "')\">" . [данные] . "</div>";
```

и потом так:

```
function cock(company_name) {
    document.getElementById('name').textContent = company_name;
}
```

Таким образом, на клике по элементу списка в js функцию передастся имя компании, которое потом вставится в нужное место. Кстати, в твоём первоначальном варианте если результатов поиска больше 1, то при клике всегда бы вставлялось одно и то же значение, которые ты жестко записал в js функцию.

Comment: поощряете js в html коде, нехорошо) все нужно выносить в отдельные файлы `.js`